# Storing locally Google's Recaptcha script

Tags: javascript, copy-paste, recaptcha

I'm using Google's reCaptcha script:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

in my web pages. I was curious, if I could store it locally and use it so that browser doesn't have to make an external call to get that js script. I wanted to copy and paste the file but when I checked it's source, it says to no to copy-paste it:

```
/* PLEASE DO NOT COPY AND PASTE THIS CODE. */(function() {if (!window['___grecaptcha_cfg']) { window['___grecaptcha_cfg'] = {}; };if (!window['___grecaptcha_cfg']['render']) { window['___grecaptcha_cfg']['render'] = 'onload'; };window['__google_recaptcha_client'] = true;var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;po.src = 'https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20160216085053/recaptcha__en.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);})();
```

Is there a way around to save that external call?

Answer (score 3):

Making the effort to save the small amount of loading time, which is not blocking by the way, is a total waste of your time. You probably spent more time asking this question than you'll be able to get back out by using a more optimized version.

> Is there a way around to save that external call?

You can copy and paste it, if you want your Recaptcha implementation to break in the future. The problem is when Google decides to change what the script does, you will not be running the updated version.

Comment: You can easily update the locally hosted api.js with a hourly crontab

Comment: FWIW some networks may be restricted and not allow 3rd party downloads, in which case the reCAPTCHA script (and others) would need to be "bundled".